# What's the difference between http_build_str() and http_build_query()?

Tags: php

I just discover these functions seems redundant.
`http_build_query()` belong to  standard php functions.
`http_build_str()` is part of pecl_http package.

are they 100% redundant ?

I am focused on getting the perfect reverse function of `parse_str()`. since `http_build query()` is broken. ( see [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930592/http-build-query-ignores-the-key-if-the-value-is-an-empty-array-how-is-this-not) )
I  wondering if there is some way that `http_build_str()` could have any advantage to support/tolerate more edge cases.

Comment: Why don't you just read the API?

Comment: Because build_query was introduced in PHP 5. There's no reason to have the pecl version installed unless you're on an old version of PHP, and/or are trying shove a php4 codebase into a php5 install.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, you bring the first valuable input ;-) I also updated my question to be more specific

Comment: @thatidiotguy it is not that obvious, one could think that http_build_str does that by default and API just "does not say" that... also since http_build_str accepts only arrays - so you could also think it's some "legacy" funciton...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By reading the API, it appears that `http_build_str()` does not URL encode the parameters, while `http_build_query()` does.

`http_build_str()` also can take either an object OR an object as its primary argument, while `http_build_query()` only takes an array.

Comment: sorry I was too vague and updated my question with more details.

Comment: @lenzai Because of the way PHP evolved, it is riddled with functions that have duplicate purpose. It was difficult to do major revisions and leave stuff backwards compatible so the language is littered with references to old extensions that are really no longer needed if you use the updated versions of the core language.

Comment: 2 duplicate functions for similar purpose for historical reason is annoying but makes sens. Still none of them is a perfect reverse of parse_str :(

Answer (score 2):

Redundant to an extent. But, if you refer to the PHP documentation, you ought to see distinct differences:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php

In the very least, you ought to see that  http_build_query() is core PHP and supports an additional encoding style parameter. And you ought to see that http_build_str() is a PECL extension.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But what's the point of having 2 function. Besides the "official reverse of `parse_str` ( a builtin php function ) is not `http_build_query` ( another builtin php function ) but `http_build_str` ( an external PECL extension). Is not that confusing ? How to make sens of that and wisely chose between the 2?

Comment: No. The [parse_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) documentation refers/links to http_build_query(), NOT the pecl extension! So, if there is an "official" inverse, it is NOT the pecl function. And as is mentioned above, the pecl version was undoubtedly just created before http_build_query() was integrated into core PHP.

Comment: you are right. I got confused with the fact that `http_build_Str()` claims to be the reverse of `parse_str()` whereas `http_build_query()` does not.